# AAPT error: check logs for details

Tags: aapt

I have put android.enableAapt2=false on gradle.properties,but still have problem,like this :

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
```

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error: check logs for details
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error: check logs for details

Comment: Like Henrique said, disabling AAPT2 is not a good solution (in this case it even doesn't solve the issue). There is probably something wrong in your resources. The exact resource where the error is coming from should be included in the build log. Go to the Terminal window in Android Studio and run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" and edit the question to contain the output, then I can tell you what exactly is the reason you're getting this error.